# AQL: How to filter where NOT IN edge

Tags: arangodb, aql

**TASK**: Get random friend suggestions from `User` collection.

This is a User collection example:

```
{
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "username": "johndoe",
  "email": "john@doe.com"
}
```

I also have an edge collection `friendRequest` that stores friend requests like this:

```
_from: "User/John" -> _to: "User/Jane"
```

**PROBLEM**: I want to filter out my self and Users I already sent a request to.

This is my initial query to get 3 users excluding myself

```
FOR user IN User
FILTER user._key != 'myself'
SORT RAND()
LIMIT 3
RETURN user
```

I want to be able to exclude people I've already sent a request to using something like `FILTER NOT IN (<<SOME EDGE QUERY>>)`

**NOTE**: I also have a graph `friendRequest_graph` that relates `friendRequest` edge between `User` collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I can do that with this query!

```
FOR user IN User
  FILTER user._key != 'myself' && 
  user._key NOT IN (FOR fr IN friendRequest FILTER fr._from == 'User/myself' RETURN LTRIM(fr._to, 'User/'))
  SORT RAND()
  LIMIT 3
  RETURN user
```

Comment: To compute the document key from a document ID like `User/John`, you can use `PARSE_IDENTIFIER()`: `RETURN PARSE_IDENTIFIER(fr._to).key` -  https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Functions/Document.html#parseidentifier